# Writing highly asynchronous code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am writing a new web service that will be performing a lot of large data load operations. To do so I am moving the data to a temporary table then merging the data in to the live data via a stored procedure.

That part I have down and working and am very confident in. What I am doing now is trying to optimize the loading code to help take the load off of the IIS server that will be performing these operations.

Here is what I am currently doing synchronously and works fine.

```
public void BulkLoadData(IDataReaderWithMappings reader, 
                         string createTempTableStatement, 
                         string loadingStoredProcedureName)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(createTempTableStatement, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "#temp";
        var mappings = reader.GetMappings();
        foreach (var sqlBulkCopyColumnMapping in mappings)
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(sqlBulkCopyColumnMapping);
        }
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = loadingStoredProcedureName;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt at translating that in to asynchronous code.

```
public async Task BulkLoadDataAsync(IDataReaderWithMappings reader, 
                                    string createTempTableStatement, 
                                    string loadingStoredProcedureName)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(createTempTableStatement))
    {
        var firstStage =  connection.OpenAsync()
                                    .ContinueWith(async delegate
        {
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        });

        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "#temp";
        var mappings = reader.GetMappings();
        foreach (var sqlBulkCopyColumnMapping in mappings)
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(sqlBulkCopyColumnMapping);
        }

        //Wait for the connection opening and the create table task to finish.
        await firstStage.ConfigureAwait(false);

        await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader).ConfigureAwait(false);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = loadingStoredProcedureName;
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The part I am not sure of my self about is that `.ContinueWith(` section. I thought it would be good to start opening the connection and creating the temporary table while I populate the bulk copy column mappings, and I have used async/await many times before but this is the first time I have used `.ContinueWith(` in conjunction with the async/await syntax.

Did I do it correctly, or should that `await firstStage;` be `await firstStage.Unwrap();`? I still do not exactly understand when I should be using `Unwrap()`. **EDIT**: Ok, `Unwrap()` is not listed so I could not use it even if I wanted to, but if anyone wants to include a explanation in their answer of when I should I would appreciate it.

(P.S. Do not worry about SQL injection from `createTempTableStatement` the strings being passed in are hard-coded resource strings with no user input.)

---

With the suggestions from svick and some other tweaks I made while waiting for an answer here is the final version

```
public async Task BulkLoadDataAsync(IDataReader reader, 
                                    string createTempTableStatement, 
                                    string loadingStoredProcedureName, 
                                    params SqlParameter[] args)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(createTempTableStatement))
    {
        Func<Task> firstStageFunc = async () => 
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        };

        var firstStage = firstStageFunc();

        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "#temp";
        var mappedReader = reader as IDataReaderWithMappings;
        if (mappedReader != null)
        {
            var mappings = mappedReader.GetMappings();
            foreach (var sqlBulkCopyColumnMapping in mappings)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(sqlBulkCopyColumnMapping);
            }
        }

        //Wait for the connection opening and the create table task to finish.
        await firstStage.ConfigureAwait(false);
        var bulkCopyTask = bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = loadingStoredProcedureName;

        if (args != null)
            command.Parameters.AddRange(args);

        //Wait for the bulk copy to finish.
        await bulkCopyTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to combine `ContinueWith()` and `async` this way, then you **need** to use `Unwrap()`. (And it *is* available, though my ReSharper doesn't seem to think so, maybe you use that too?) If you don't do that, you're not actually waiting for `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` to complete.

But using `ContinueWith()` is usually not a good idea when you can use `await`. Instead, you can use a helper method:

```
private static async Task FirstStageAsync(SqlConnection connection, SqlCommand command)
{
    await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And then in the main method:

```
var firstStage = FirstStageAsync(connection, command);

…

//Wait for the connection opening and the create table task to finish.
await firstStage.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Another option would be use a lambda instead of the helper method:

```
Func<Task> firstStageFunc = async () =>
{
    await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
};

var firstStage = firstStageFunc();
```

Comment: I do use resharper, and actually I ended up re-writing the code to use a helper method anyway since I asked the question because I thought it looked "cleaner".